# How to write multiple line string using Bash with variables?

Tags: linux, bash, bash4

How can I write multi-lines in a file called `myconfig.conf` using BASH?

```
#!/bin/bash
kernel="2.6.39";
distro="xyz";

echo <<< EOL
line 1, ${kernel}
line 2,
line 3, ${distro}
line 4
line ...
EOL >> /etc/myconfig.conf;
cat /etc/myconfig.conf;
```

Answer (score 644, accepted):

The syntax (`<<<`) and the command used (`echo`) is wrong.

Correct would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

kernel="2.6.39"
distro="xyz"
cat >/etc/myconfig.conf <<EOL
line 1, ${kernel}
line 2, 
line 3, ${distro}
line 4 line
... 
EOL

cat /etc/myconfig.conf
```

This construction is referred to as a [Here Document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) and can be found in the Bash man pages under `man --pager='less -p "\s*Here Documents"' bash`.

Comment: and if you want to append it would be cat >>

Comment: This works great, but you have to make sure that there's no whitespace in front of the terminating `EOF`, otherwise it will not be recognized, and you will run into an _unexpected end of file_ error.

Comment: Is there a term for this?

Comment: @StevenEckhoff This is called a heredoc.

Comment: What if I need sudo permission to write to the file?

Comment: @gfpacheco You can use tee for that, like cat << EOL | sudo tee /etc/myconfig.conf

Comment: @gfpacheco If using tee, don't forget that you can need -a to append

Comment: what if you want to literally write "${distro}" to a file instead of substituting it for "xyz"?

Comment: @waspinator As usual, you can escape characters with \. In your case, it would be `\${distro}`.

Comment: Now, how do you do this withOUT expanding variables inside the multi-line string?

Comment: Got it: simply put the first `EOL` usage in quotes. See here: https://linuxize.com/post/bash-heredoc/. That makes the first line of the heredoc look like this: `cat > /etc/myconfig.conf << 'EOL'` instead of like this: `cat > /etc/myconfig.conf << EOL`. Now it will NOT do variable expansion before writing to the file. Excellent! Note: I know that's kind of the opposite of this question, but that's what I want, and googling for it landed me here.

Comment: This doesn't work for me :(

Comment: `The last line ends with the delimiting identifier. White space in front of the delimiter is not allowed`, as documented in https://linuxize.com/post/bash-heredoc/

So, if you use this in a function, it doesn't work if you add spaces or tab in front of `EOL`

Answer (score 106):

```
#!/bin/bash
kernel="2.6.39";
distro="xyz";

cat > /etc/myconfig.conf << EOL
line 1, ${kernel}
line 2,
line 3, ${distro}
line 4
line ...
EOL
```

this does what you want.

Comment: @ktf I was typing not faster, but less letters than you. ^_*

Comment: You were faster but its not enough :))))

Comment: This helped a lot!

Answer (score 55):

If you do not want variables to be replaced, you need to surround EOL with single quotes.

```
cat >/tmp/myconfig.conf <<'EOL'
line 1, ${kernel}
line 2, 
line 3, ${distro}
line 4 line
... 
EOL
```

Previous example:

```
$ cat /tmp/myconfig.conf 
line 1, ${kernel}
line 2, 
line 3, ${distro}
line 4 line
...
```

Comment: Thanks for nuance when I don't wanna modify variables. e.g. having it in quotes `'EOL'`

Answer (score 19):

The heredoc solutions are certainly the most common way to do this.  Other common solutions are:

```
echo 'line 1, '"${kernel}"'
line 2,
line 3, '"${distro}"'
line 4' > /etc/myconfig.conf
```

and

```
exec 3>&1 # Save current stdout
exec > /etc/myconfig.conf
echo line 1, ${kernel}
echo line 2, 
echo line 3, ${distro}
...
exec 1>&3  # Restore stdout
```

and

```
printf "%s\n" "line1, ${kernel}" "line2," "line3, $distro" ...
```

Comment: Maybe also point to `printf` which introduces yet some more interesting variations.

Answer (score 10):

I'm using **Mac OS** and to write multiple lines in a **SH Script** following code worked for me

```
#! /bin/bash
FILE_NAME="SomeRandomFile"

touch $FILE_NAME

echo """I wrote all
the  
stuff
here.
And to access a variable we can use
$FILE_NAME  

""" >> $FILE_NAME

cat $FILE_NAME
```

Please don't forget to assign chmod as required to the script file.
I have used

```
chmod u+x myScriptFile.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

Below mechanism helps in redirecting multiple lines to file. Keep complete string under `"` so that we can redirect values of the variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
kernel="2.6.39"
echo "line 1, ${kernel}
line 2," > a.txt
echo 'line 2, ${kernel}
line 2,' > b.txt
```

Content of `a.txt` is

```
line 1, 2.6.39
line 2,
```

Content of `b.txt` is

```
line 2, ${kernel}
line 2,
```

Answer (score 0):

In my usecase I had to use the following:

```bash
{
 ...
 printf "Suites: $SUITES"
 printf "Components: $COMPONENTS"
 printf "Signed-By: $SIGNATURE"
 [ ! -z "$ARCH_STRING" ] && printf "$ARCH_STRING"
 [ ! -z "$LANG_STRING" ] && printf "$LANG_STRING"
 [ ! -z "$TARGET_STRING" ] && printf "$TARGET_STRING"
 ...
} > /tmp/myconfig.conf
```

This because I did not want to write empty newlines to the file if the variables were not defined. The nice thing about this method is that you can write all kinds of arbitrary logic within the block if necessary.

And ofcourse, if you would like to append, you can also use `>>` here instead of `>` like you would in the other answers.

Answer (score -1):

I usually put template in file and use this templating engine:

```sh
### <template-file> [ARG=VALUE..]
## Variables are replaced only within "{{" and "}}" notation.
## Example:
##         $0 path-to-tmpl REF=master pass=xx
##         # The template may look like so:
##         #    $pass = ["user", "{{ $pass }}"];
##         # Resulting in:
##         #    $pass = ["user", "xxx"];
##~
template() {
    tmpl=$1
    shift

    for i in $@; do
        declare $i;
    done

    eval "echo \"$(sed -e 's/"/\\"/g' -e 's/\$/\\$/g' -e 's/{{\s*\\\(\$\w*\)\s*}}/\1/g' $tmpl)\""
}
```

Answer (score -3):

another simpler way I think but definitely for small number of lines

```
touch myfile.txt
echo "line1">>myfile.txt
echo "line2">>myfile.txt
echo "line3">>myfile.txt
echo "line4">>myfile.txt
```