# Exclude a folder with .artifactignore

Tags: azure-devops, artifact

I'm building a pipeline where my staging directory looks like this:

```
.
└── a
    ├── b
    │   ├── c   <-- exclude everything under this
    │   │   └── d
    │   │       ├── big_file_1
    │   │       └── big_file_2
    │   ├── file_1
    │   └── file_2
    ├── file_3
    └── file_4
```

What I want is to exclude everything under `c` from my artifact. The files under `c` can be deeply nested and the number of levels is unpredictable. I learned that `.artifactignore`, while advertising that it works like `.gitignore`, is anything but. If I want to exclude `c`, all I had to do in `.gitignore` is:

```
**/c
```

I tried that, plus countless other patterns in `.artfifactignore` but can't make it to work. Here's a YAML pipeline if you want to replicate the problem:

```yaml
steps:
  - bash: |
      mkdir -p a/b/c/d
      touch a/b/c/d/big_file_1
      touch a/b/c/d/big_file_2

      touch a/b/file_1
      touch a/b/file_2
      touch a/file_3
      touch a/file_4

      echo > .artifactignore <<EOF
      **/c
      **/c/*
      **/c/**
      **/c/**/*
      a/b/c/**
      **/big*
      EOF

      tree
    workingDirectory: $(Build.StagingDirectory)

  - publish: $(Build.StagingDirectory)
    name: drop
    displayName: Publish
```

None of the patterns worked! How am I supposed to exclude `c` directory with `.artifactignore`?

Comment: Did you look at the `.artifactignore` documentation? *To assure the proper execution, .artifactignore file should be checked into the root of the repository.*

Comment: Plenty of people, include a Microsoft MVP, says that I should place it at the target path of the `publish` task: https://www.jfe.cloud/control-pipeline-artifacts-with-artifactignore-file/

Comment: I just tried placing it at the root of the repo. No difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done some very minor ("cat" instead of "echo") updates in your pipeline and it works fine for me.

My pipeline:

```
trigger:
  - none

stages:
  - stage: first
    jobs: 
     - job: firstJob
       continueOnError: false
       steps:
         - bash: |
             mkdir -p a/b/c/d
             touch a/b/c/d/big_file_1
             touch a/b/c/d/big_file_2

             touch a/b/file_1
             touch a/b/file_2
             touch a/file_3
             touch a/file_4

             cat > .artifactignore <<EOF
             **/c
             EOF
             
             tree
           workingDirectory: $(Build.StagingDirectory)
         - publish: $(Build.StagingDirectory)
           name: drop
           displayName: Publish
```

---

Output for Tree:

[image]

---

Published artifact:

[image]

---

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/reference/artifactignore?view=azure-devops
- https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore
- [How to write multiple line string using Bash with variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875540/how-to-write-multiple-line-string-using-bash-with-variables)

Comment: Hm... interesting that `cat` fixes the problem but while `echo` blew it. I will mark this as the accepted answer

Comment: I would suggest you to read the third reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875540/how-to-write-multiple-line-string-using-bash-with-variables) for clear explanation.