redirect operator fail to create file using groovy in a dockerized jenkins
Im checking to create a step in my pipeline to save state of file like this:
sh '''
   echo "
   my commands
   " > state

But appears Syntax error: redirection unexpected
Im using standard jenkins image from docker and Im not sure If is a problem from image to be based on debian and not include redirect operators

try to use another syntax for shell multiline strings https://stackoverflow.com/a/7875614/1276664

I'm pretty sure your repro is missing something, because if you run exactly that (assuming the missing closing triple single quote is an SO artifact) on an official Jenkins image it works as expected.

I answer with the solution, was a OS problem using docker image.

Problem is for the use of a limited Debian inside jenkins image. By default jenkins seems to use /bin/sh  but debian not include > operators in this shell system. Default shell from this image is /bin/dash instead of /bin/bash. Basically to solve this you need to go to System > Shell and insert it. Works how expected

"but debian not include > operators in this shell system" What?! This is wrong.

please, read all first, Im refering to this docker image, not using Debian

This docker image - jenkins/jenkins - supports IO redirection. In all of its shells. Easy to verify docker run jenkins/jenkins /bin/dash -c 'echo Foo > ~/bar; cat ~/bar'. Replace /bin/dash with /bin/sh or /bin/bash to test those shells. A linux shell that doesn't support IO redirection is unheard of.
